# Google Invisible reCaptcha Wordpress without plugin

Tags: javascript, html, captcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have callback plugin on my Wordpress web-site and try to add invisible recaptcha without using WP plugin. I tried some ways but no result. Can you correct a right code for jquery validation form I've already have?
I have input button in my form. PHP and HTML I can correct by myself.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('.callback-form-container').submit(function() {
                    var formInputs = $(this).find('.validate');
                    var errors = '';
                    $(formInputs).each(function() {
                        if($.trim(this.value) == '') {
                            fieldLabel = $(this).parent().find('span.label-text').html();
                            errors += '- ' + fieldLabel + '\n';
                        }
                    });
                    if(errors.length > 0) {
                        alert('Error:\n\n' + errors);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.submit-button').val('Please wait...');
                        $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        return true;
                    }

                    });
                });
function onSubmit1(token){
        document.getElementById("send").submit();
};
```

Comment: have you entered correct secret key in captcha.php?

Comment: yeah. I think problem in jquery code